# How to show trailing spaces, while leaving tabs as they are?

Tags: indentation, options, whitespace

I like the ability to show trailing whitespaces, so I have this setting.

`set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·`

I never use tabs (although I don't think tabs are bad, it's just a convention), but sometimes I'm reading someone else code and they use tabs. I don't want to see tabs as some special characters in that cases.

But with the settings above vim would show tabs with different background colour. I don't want this. Can it just show trailing whitespaces and leave everything else alone?

Comment: AFAIK, `'listchars'` isn't supposed to change background. You can for sure try to drop `tab:\ \ ` part, but I wouldn't expect it to change anything (that's the default). Highlighting of tabulation might come from a different source. You can run `:for id in synstack(line('.'), col('.')) | echo synIDattr(id, 'name') | endfor` with cursor on a tab to see if there is any extra highlight group defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can omit `tab` from `listchars`, but that will cause vim to fall back on the default (showing tabs as `^I`). So using `tab:\ \` as you have is a reasonable way to keep them "invisible" when `list` is set.

The characters shown with `list` are highlighted with the `SpecialKey` or `NonText` groups, depending. Tabs, in particular, use `SpecialKey`, so it sounds like your color scheme has a background color for that particular group (see: `:help listchars` for more).

Unfortunately `SpecialKey` is used for `trail` as well, so whatever changes you make there for `tab` will apply to `trail` as well. If you go this route, you will only be able to change the foreground color of `SpecialKey`, really, without visibly impacting the tabs.

One alternative might be to avoid using `list` at all; in your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax match TrailingSpace /\s\+$/
hi TrailingSpace guibg=red
```

for example, will highlight trailing whitespace with a red background independent of whatever you have going on with `list`.

Comment: Thanks for an idea about syntax match. Can I also display some character instead of space that way? Probably not...

Comment: You might be able to abuse concealment (:help syn-conceal) but I don't think that will end up working well.